# Blank/White Screen on Frontend but Accessible backend?

Tags: fatal-error

I have this issue, where I can't access the frontend without a blank page anymore. It drives me crazy.

The backend seems to be up just fine, but the frontend is white. When trying to chose another theme (twentyten) this one also returns white, already in the preview.

I've turned on debug in wp-config after following another thread and it has come up with the following errors:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/dali/public_html/wilds/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/wildsofo/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 14
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/dali/public_html/wilds/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in
>   /home/wildsofo/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 14

What can I possibly do?

Website: wildsofoldham.co.uk

Comment: Do you have super cache plugin in plugins folder ?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, nothing about debugging and disabling themes/plugins was useful... After some research, I've realized that my `index.php` was empty!
The only content was a message saying *Silence is golden*.
Using a backup I had, I could get back my original `index.php` and get the site working again.

Comment: Thanks man. I have the same problem i dont know how it it possible the index getting like this.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't delete the htaccess.  Just rename it for testing.  (don't do this first though)

To find out what your error is though do this:

Turn on debugging in your wp-config.php file.  Do this by changing this line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Hit save.

Load the front page and you should now see the actual error.  Use this to fix the problem.

If you can't resolve it this way, disable plugins by renaming the plugins folder to something else.  Does your site load now?  If it does, change the plugins back to "plugins" and deactivate all your plugins in the dashboard.  Re-enable them 1 by 1 until you find the trouble-causing one.

Feel free to change the wp-config back once you're done testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

1. Try to disable the wp-super-cache plugin or delete it completely
   through ftp.
2. Delete the .htaccess  located within root
3. Check the wp-config.php for any line which is not a WordPress default and comment out.
4. Go to admin > Settings > Permalinks > save once**

At this moment the front end should be visible.

If still not working, check with the **server errors log** which should reveal the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, check that your server is actually loading index.php as the priority.In my case, I was moving a WordPress site to a new server, I hadn't noticed that there was a default.html file in the root directory that, under the new server, prioritized loading `default.html` over `index.php`.  There were no error logs, even loading `index.php` didn't work since WordPress automatically redirects `index.php` to `mysite.com/`, which would load the empty `default.html` file.

To ensure `index.php` is loading before others, add this line to your `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your Wordpress installation's `index.php`.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```